# error Cannot read property '1' of undefined when access array inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i am writing my object in this format 
`var eqres = [{"datapoints": [[1, 1530034200], [1, 1530034200]]}]`

[i have attached the image of consolelog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pvZ4.png)

i am trying to update the values of 1530034200 and 1530034200 by accessing it like

```
eqres[0].datapoints[1][1] , eqres[0].datapoints[0][1]
```

i am getting the error Cannot read property '1' of undefined

I am getting the data from an api and writing it into eqres

```
var eqres ={};
var eqres = [{'datapoints': [] }];
var ee = this.doRequest({
  url: urll,
  headers: 
    {
      'X-xxx': this.uname,
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'X-xxx': timestamp,
      'X-xxx': hash_string
    },
  method: 'GET'}).then(response => response.data.data.row)
  .then(function(j)
  {
     var ff = j;
     for (var i in ff)
       {
         eqres[0]['datapoints'].push([ff[i].col[1],ff[i].col[0]]);
       };

  })
```

I am trying to update it like this

```
var now = Date.now();
for (var i = eqres.length -1; i >= 0; i--) 
{
  var series = eqres[i];
  var decreaser = 0;
  for (var y = series.datapoints.length -1; y >= 0; y--) 
  {
    series.datapoints[y][1] = Math.round((now - decreaser) /1000) * 1000;
    decreaser += 50000;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post more code? the sample you posted works fine for me so the problem must be elsewhere, ie, `var eqres = [{"datapoints": [[1, 1530034200], [1, 1530034200]]}]; console.log(eqres[0].datapoints[1][1] , eqres[0].datapoints[0][1]); // 1530034200 1530034200`

Comment: Are you reading these datapoints from a file or an API? You may need to use `JSON.parse` to convert the JSON string into an object.

Comment: @JakeMiller i am getting the data from an API and it is already an object

Comment: Can you show all of your code? Including the part where you attempt to modify the data inside of datapoints? The example data you posted works fine.

Comment: Even with all of the updates you posted, your code runs without errors. Can you highlight the exact line that's causing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine if you hardcode the `eqres` datapoints directly into a variable. What I'm thinking is you're attempting to access datapoints *before* your asynchronous API request finishes. Try running your modification code in another `then` call after your API completes like so:

```
var eqres ={};
var eqres = [{'datapoints': [] }];
var ee = this.doRequest({
  url: urll,
  headers: 
  {
    'X-xxx': this.uname,
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'X-xxx': timestamp,
    'X-xxx': hash_string
  },
  method: 'GET'}).then(response => response.data.data.row)
.then(function(j) {
  var ff = j;
  for (var i in ff)
  {
    eqres[0]['datapoints'].push([ff[i].col[1],ff[i].col[0]]);
  };
})
.then(function() {
  var now = Date.now();
  for (var i = eqres.length -1; i >= 0; i--) 
  {
    var series = eqres[i];
    var decreaser = 0;
    for (var y = series.datapoints.length -1; y >= 0; y--) 
    {
      series.datapoints[y][1] = Math.round((now - decreaser) /1000) * 1000;
      decreaser += 50000;
    }
  }
});
```

Now your datapoints will be available to you when you attempt to modify them.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation i always use this debug code:

```
console.log(eqres[0]);
console.log(eqres[0].datapoints);
console.log(eqres[0].datapoints[1]);
console.log(eqres[0].datapoints[1][1]);
```

and now tell me wich line throws error and show result of one line above.

Comment: i am writing the data in that format, i am getting the result if i run it directly in console log , but its throwing an error when i am writing in that format and accessing it

Comment: ok, did you try changing updating line to: series["datapoints"][y][1] = Math.round((now - decreaser) /1000) * 1000;
second, check if series["datapoints"][y] is not undefined